# Reusing TCP port of a killed process

Tags: kill, tcp

I have a TCP server process on Linux. It sometimes gets killed by `SIGKILL`, after which its parent restarts it. I cannot change the way the child is killed. Sometimes (about once per 100 times) the restart fails because the server port is still in use (`bind` returns `EADDRINUSE`). The socket options explicitly set by server are `O_RDWR`, `O_NONBLOCK` `TCP_NODELAY`, `SO_REUSEADDR` and `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT`.

My questions are:

1. If a process that has a non-blocking TCP socket operation in process is killed, will its buffers be flushed and the port put in `TIME_WAIT` before its parent will get `SIGCHILD`?
2. When parent gets `SIGCHILD` for a killed child, is it guaranteed that the ports used by the child can be reused with `SO_REUSEADDR`?
3. Does this behaviour differ on different Linux kernels and on Mac?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the server gets killed by the `KILL` signal. Does it do a proper cleanup if you kill it with e.g. `TERM` instead, or terminate it in some other way?

Comment: Kusalananda, as I wrote, changing the way it is killed is not an option. I am interested in the behaviour of Linux kernel when killing a process with `SIGKILL`.

Comment: By terminating a server process (or any process) with the `KILL` signal, you give it no opportunity whatsoever to clean up (close connections, flush output etc.) This is the nature of that signal, and why it should not be used.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda. But the kernel does the actual cleanup of the resources associated with the killed process, and the kernel notifies the parent process of the child being killed. What I am interested in is the guarantees of the order of these actions taken by the kernel.